# Is there a way to install python 3.12 on ubuntu 23.04 through apt?

Tags: apt, python, 23.04

There's no python 3.12 in Main or Universe and deadsnakes doesn't support it for 23.04. I'm hoping to avoid having to compile it from source (since I want to use it in Docker images based off of 23.04).

Comment: Don't mess with the default python on Ubuntu. Use the source version, install in /opt  (it is as simple as un-tarring the download) and create an python env.

Comment: https://github.com/deadsnakes/python3.12 claims support for Ubuntu. But you need their focal or jammy repo and it will install on 23.04 or 23.10 I have been using it myself for a week now.

Comment: @Rinzwind ah, do you mean something like `sudo add-apt-repository -u 'jammy' ppa:deadsnakes/ppa`?

Comment: Download anaconda and set up a virtual environment for python 3.12 https://www.anaconda.com/download/

Comment: @Rinzwind yeah, running `add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa ` fails with `E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu lunar Release' does not have a Release file`, I'm surprised it works for you on 23.04, did you mess with the apt config files?

Comment: You can change the repo @nobilis Just open the source file and alter it

Comment: forgot to update that I ended up abandoning this as I started to run into `AttributeError: module 'pkgutil' has no attribute 'ImpImporter'. Did you mean: 'zipimporter'?` which seems is something other people run into too

Answer (score 0):

**Use a virtual environment to resolve your issue.**

- Updating Python in Ubuntu can cause compatibility issues with system components and applications. Ubuntu relies on specific Python versions for its internal processes, and updating Python could disrupt these dependencies.
- **Use a Python Version Manager:** Consider using a Python version manager like Pyenv or asdf to manage multiple Python versions on your system. These tools allow you to install and switch between different Python versions easily, and you can create virtual environments with any installed Python version.

Let me know if any further information is needed.